# name 'application' does not exist in the current context

Tags: outlook, vsto, ribbon

Hi I'm working to develop a solution to creating a toolbar in Outlook 2010 using VSTO 2012 and the microsoft outlook 2010 addin. In a nutshell I am able to create the Outlook ribbon and a button but I am unable to get the button to open an .oft file. In Visual Studio I get the following error "The name 'application' does not exist in the current context". I have added a reference to the Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library also. Below is the code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

namespace OutlookAddIn8
{
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void CreateItemFromTemplate()
    {
        Outlook.Folder folder =
            Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Outlook.Folder;
        Outlook.MailItem mail =
            Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(
            @"c:\ivy.oft", folder) as Outlook.MailItem;
        mail.Subject = "Congratulations";
        mail.Save();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Thanks any help is appreciated it is probably something simple thats been missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of Application can be accessed using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`. If you renamed your AddIn class to something different e.g. MyAddIn then the command will be: `Globals.MyAddIn.Application`.

Here is a link with more details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157876(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay so where do I enter that string. Sorry i'm not a coder just trying to get this done from bits i've found online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just add at the beginning of your function: `Outlook.Application Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;`

Comment: Brilliant thanks that got rid of the error message. Problem now is that I need code to initialise the oft on the click of a button.     private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e){    I have this part of code but where would I put it?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got there in the end, heres the code.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace OutlookAddIn3
{
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Outlook.MailItem mail =
            Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(
            @"Z:\Transfer\Outlook 2010 Templates\testsubject.oft") as Outlook.MailItem;
        mail.Display(true);
    }
```